# Windows Batch File: Loop on rows and split string

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, cmd

I have a text file with the following format:

```
name1:surname1
name2:surname2
name3:surname3
```

and so on.

I need to write a for loop in window batch script and assign to 2 variables

```
name=name1
surname=surname1
```

and so on. Something like (this is wrong)

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%row in (myfile.txt) do (
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%u in ("%row%") do (
 .... 
 )
)
```

Any suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need two nested loops for that.

What you probably will need, however, is delayed variable expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%u in (myfile.txt) do (
    set "name=%%u"
    set "surname=%%v"

    echo !surname!, !name!
)
```

outputs this for me:

```
surname1, name1
surname2, name2
surname3, name3
```

Delayed variable expansion is what allows you to assign the single-letter loop variables (`u` and `v` in this case) to real variables and use *them* in the rest of the loop, by accessing them with `!` instead of `%`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%r in (myfile.txt) do (
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%u in ("%%r") do (
 .... 
 )
)
```

or

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%u in (myfile.txt) do (
.... 
)
```

Metavariables live `r` and `u` are limited to a single (case-sensitive) alphabetical character.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%u in (myfile.txt) do (
    set name=%%u
    set surname=%%v

    echo name=!name!
    echo surname=!surname!
)
```

output:

```
name=name1
surname=surname1
name=name2
surname=surname2
name=name3
surname=surname3
```